# Как вместо ссылки сделать активный текст?

Tags: html, url, ссылки

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как составить программу или что нужно делать, чтобы вместо длинной ссылки активным было одно слово. Например, вместо ссылки

```
http://www.stroy-birzha.ru/request/?code=ffa8ce586819
```

Чтобы было слово

```
Строй-Биржа.рф
```

Или вместо ссылки

```
http://m.seaman-santehnika.ru/products/smesitel-seaman-eco-venice-ssn-1394p1/
```

Было активным слово смеситель с выдвижной лейкой? Спасибо всем, кто откликнется!

Comment: @натальяya, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 6):

Надо обернуть слово в тег `<a>` (от англ. anchor, якорь):

```
<a href="сюда идёт длинная ссылка" >слово</a>
```

Например:

```
<a href="http://www.stroy-birzha.ru/request/?code=ffa8ce586819">Строй-Биржа.рф</a>
```